# Swift. dyld: Library not loaded

Tags: swift, dyld

I've added a custom library (attach project) to my project.
If I use it in `main.swift` all is good.
But, if I try to make it like:

```
import ARISockets

class MyClass {
    var listenSocket : PassiveSocketIPv4?
}
```

then it gives an error

> dyld: Library not loaded

PS: I make Command Line Tool for a mac

PSS: Add library https://github.com/AlwaysRightInstitute/SwiftSockets